# How to create a object with keys name from variables

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to create this object:

```
{ 2020 : 
        { november: 
                   { 26: 'test'}
        }
}
```

but i end up like this:

```
{ year : 
        { month: 
                   { day: 'test'}
        }
}
```

javascript:

```
year = 2020 
month = november
day = 26

testarray.push({ year :{
        month: {day: 'test'} }
        });
    }
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `testarray.push({ [year] :{[month]: {[day]: 'test'} }});}`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const year = 2020;
const month = 'november';
const day = 26;

const testarray = [];

testarray.push({
  [year]: {
    [month]: { [day]: 'test' }
  }
});

console.log(testarray);
```